# Default folder display when click on Download (from Firefox or any navigator) on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: directory, downloads, browser, default

**Update :** I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and Firefox is set to "Always ask you where to save files".

I want to change the default folder displaying when I'm clicking on something to download from my browser. At this time when I try to download something, the system displays this folder : /run/user/1000/doc/269dc7f4. I would like that it displays the /home folder in place of the one above.

Can someone tell me how to do this. I didn't find any thread about this.

**Update :** Firefox version is 98.0.2 64bit Snap canonical-002-1.0

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Have you explored all the various option in the Firefox config? I also do not see any mention of Ubuntu in your question. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This is Firefox installed and running as a snap. It is one of these usability issues that should be solved.

Comment: I faced the same issue, on Ubuntu 22.04, Firefox version is 120.0.2